# Apache Camel JMS memory leak?

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

I am a newbie in using Apache camel, yet from various tests of mine I realize that using JMS  as a queue channel it creates a memory leak, as the used memory is not reduced after each message's consumption.

a simple example would describe it better:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
    context.addComponent("experimental", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("file://test").to("experimental:queue:test");
        }
    });
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("experimental:queue:test").to("stream:out");
        }
    });
    Main main = new Main();
    main.getCamelContexts().add(context);
    main.run();
}
```

Is there any way to force GC to clean the Queue or flush its content on demand?
Is there a better way to Use Camel for such solutions?

Cheers!

Comment: Why do you have all these empty anon Processor impls? They do not seem to do anything. I think your routes could be expressed as: from("file://test").to("experimental:queue:test"); from("experimental:queue:test").to("stream:out");

Comment: Yes, Processors have nothing to do with the question so I delete their content. Maybe I should had delete them as well, sorry.

Comment: I removed the empty processors. One more question. How did you diagnose the memory leak? Is the heap only growing but then gets small again after each GC or does it stay large and you get an out of memory exception after some time?

Comment: I test the following scenario; files of 2-5 MB were randomly created, so they should be parsed by workers. Then I realized heap was keep growing after each message's consumption by all "workers", which should trigger their deletion (by GC?). Then VM reached its outOfMemory. To be honest I didn't tried any optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently using activemq with the vm protocol so it creates a broker inside your process. Can you try to use an external activemq broker? If in this case there is no memory leak then the problem is in activemq. Anyway the vm protocol is mainly for testing.

Comment: Can you provide me an example of activemq as you have described it? thank you.

Comment: Download ActiveMQ, unpack and start it with defaults. Then you can use : ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

Answer (score 2):

I'd be surprised if the ActiveMQ component had a memory leak - it would have been spotted ages ago as it's a very commonly used component.

I'd take Christian's advice and actually use active MQ instead of VM, but also, I would replace the file://test endpoint with something like direct:test, and after you start your context, create a producer template and inundate the route with messages:

```
ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
long msgNumber = 1;
while (true) {

   template.sendBody("direct:test", "message number " + msgNumber);
   msgNumber++;

}
```

If that doesn't crash pretty soon then it's likely that gc is doing it's job.  You can run it in a profiler to be sure.

Comment: A huge heap was crated, yet it didn't crash.